# java default local object variable initialization

Tags: java, object, local-variables

In java OCA book Oracle Certified Associate Java SE 8 Programmer there's this QCM:
(Chap 1 question number 12)

**A local variable of type Object default to null** 
they respond that's false.

but I think that's a mistake because when we declare this for example :
Object obj; as a local variable in a method , the code compiles fine , So the object is null 
what do you think guys ?

Comment: A variable being uninitialised is not the same as being null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare `Object obj;` inside a method, `obj` is *uninitialized*. This is still totally legal to do, but you cannot access `obj` without initializing it. If you go a little farther, and write:

```
Object local;

if (local == null) {
    // something
}
```

The compiler will stop you.

Comment: The spec lays it out pretty nicely, and also points out the difference to e.g. class variables: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5